# What is the difference between clipRect and translate on the canvas class?

Tags: android, android-canvas

A clear example would help. I am confused by why I can't just use translate every time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331805/using-cliprect-explantion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clip rectangle is the drawing portion of your canvas - anything you draw outside this rectangle doesn't count - ie. doen't get finally rendered onto the display. Think of it as the boundaries of your canvas.

A canvas also has a coordinate system which starts at `0,0` A.K.A the origin and `x` increases from left to right, and `y` increases from top to down. When you use any of the drawing commands that need coodinates (e.g `drawLine`, `drawRect`), the coordinates are relative to the this coordinate system.

You can move this coordinate system by using `canvas.translate`. Think of it as a frame of reference which can be moved around