# Get bitmap from a part of canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have Canvas with a Bitmap and I draw some markers on specific positions of Canvas:

```
canvas.drawCircle( x, y, 10, paint );
```

Now I have to cut off part of that Canvas and create a Bitmap. But when I try to create a new Bitmap with:

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, w, h);
```

I don't get correct part of the image.

How can I get same part of the image like it is marked on the Canvas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331805/using-cliprect-explantion. try with clipRect

Comment: How will clipRect help me get that part of the image?